# How to display a quote in a Textview?

Tags: android, textview, bbcode

How i can show a Quote in Android Textview?

In my string i have a

```
BBCode URL IMG and [Quote] tags
```

etc work but Quote it don't convert.

---

Edit: maybe i need to write that i mean the tags :)

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the quote using `\"`

`myTextView.setText("\"");` displays `"`

Comment: Can you give me a little explanation, please?

Answer (score 1):

Use `&quot;` to add quote to a string, then set that string to the `TextView`. Take a look at the following example-

```
<TextView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Hii &quot;TextView&quot;"
 android:textSize="15sp" 
 android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
```

The above TextView will show - Hii "TextView"

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("&ldquo; " + "YOUR TEXT" + " &rdquo;"));
```